# Functions are not appearing while using TFilterRow in Talend

Tags: talend

I am using a tFilterRow to avoid empty rows. While trying to use it I am getting only one function value 'absolute value'.

[image: Screenshot of the job]

I want to filter values with a length greater than 0.

Why I am not getting any other functions?

Comment: The length function is only available to string data types. What is the data type you're using for "role_key"?

Comment: Integer, so what do I set with 'Absolute value'? I need to make sure that there is a value in Role_key column.

Comment: You can just use the "not equal to" in the third column of the component configuration and then `null` in the fourth column.

Comment: It gives an error which says the operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) int, null.

Comment: Then you are using the primitive integer which can never be null. In this case you want it to be not equal to 0 (which is the default empty value for the primitive int).

Comment: I cant set it to 0. I have a stored procedure which follows this copy operation and it requires value as 0 for new rows.

Comment: Your row_key will NEVER be empty. If it was an Integer then it could be null, but otherwise it will be 0. What problems are you actually seeing with your job where you require this filtering?

Comment: While copying from excel to sql some of the rows will have role key's value as 0. By that my Stored procedure will recognize that its a new entry and it will then add that row to the table with auto incremented role_key.

Comment: I guess its a deadlock, I might use some other column for filtering or make changes in my stored procedure.

Comment: Yes so, as per my answer, then you need to filter out any row_keys that are equal to 0. So set `Not equal to` in the operator and value as `0`

Comment: Alright, got it. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the length function is only available to schema columns that have the `String` data type.

To filter out any rows that have a null value in a column you can use a tFilterRow but configured so that the column being checked is not equal to null like so:

[image: Filter out any rows where the role_key is null]

In the case you are dealing with the primitive `int` (rather than the `Integer` class) then the primitive [can never be `null` and instead defaults to 0](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) so you'll want to set it as not equal to 0 instead.